# Get custom data attribute value and return as text in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fetch pictures from Flickr's publick fedd via `$.getJson()` and struggling a bit with adding tag names, as they are stored in a custom `data-tag` attribute:

HTML

```
<div data-tag="sun" class="gallery component"></div>
<div data-tag="moon" class="gallery component"></div>
etc...
```

As each gallery line should be composed of four random pictures with these tags, I wanted to set up a variable that would get these tag names from data-tag, but I'm unsure on how to get to them.

js/jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var flickrAPI = "http://https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
    var tagprop = $().text();
    var flickrTags = { 
        tags: tagprop,
        format: "json"
    };

    $.getJson(flickrAPI, flickrTags, flickrDisp)
});
```

I've tried `data.(value)`, but probably misplaced it, as it did not work. It's probably something really simple, it's just that I'm lacking orientation in this.

Comment: Huh? What are you trying to do?

Comment: For one thing: It's [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), not `getJson`. Your browser console should be telling you that.

Comment: I think you mean you'd like to get the `data-tag` value. If so, you can do `$('.component').data('tag');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get data attribute value try

```
$(elem).data("propName");
```

In your case it will be

```
<div data-tag="sun" class="gallery component"></div>
var tagValue = $("div").data("tag");
```

(jQuery >= 1.4.3)